# detecting POS tag pattern along with specified words

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, pos-tagger

I need to identify certain POS tags before/after certain specified words, for example the following tagged sentence:

```
[('This', 'DT'), ('feature', 'NN'), ('would', 'MD'), ('be', 'VB'), ('nice', 'JJ'), ('to', 'TO'), ('have', 'VB')]
```

can be abstracted to the form "would be" + Adjective

Similarly:

```
[('I', 'PRP'), ('am', 'VBP'), ('able', 'JJ'), ('to', 'TO'), ('delete', 'VB'), ('the', 'DT'), ('group', 'NN'), ('functionality', 'NN')]
```

is of the form "am able to" + Verb

How can I go about checking for these type of a pattern in sentences. I am using NLTK.

Comment: What do you mean "checking"?

Comment: I meant how do I detect that a pattern of the form "am able to" + Verb exists in a sentence. Or, for example, something like "would be" + Comparative Adjective exists in a sentence.

Comment: So do you want to print `True` if it exists or?

Comment: yep, I've seen examples with just matching POS, but in my case I need to match both words and POS tags, if that makes sense...

Comment: Also note that `'JJ'` isn't a comparative adjective - it's just an adjective.

Comment: @newdev14 You need to be clearer in terms of what you want to achieve. Can you give a specific input sentence and the desired output you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to check literally for "would" followed by "be", followed by some adjective, you can do this:

```
def would_be(tagged):
    return any(['would', 'be', 'JJ'] == [tagged[i][0], tagged[i+1][0], tagged[i+2][1]] for i in xrange(len(tagged) - 2))
```

The input is a POS tagged sentence (list of tuples, as per NLTK).

It checks if there are any three elements in the list such that "would" is next to "be" and "be" is next to a word tagged as an adjective ('JJ'). It will return `True` as soon as this "pattern" is matched.

You can do something very similar for the second type of sentence:

```
def am_able_to(tagged):
    return any(['am', 'able', 'to', 'VB'] == [tagged[i][0], tagged[i+1][0], tagged[i+2][0], tagged[i+3][1]] for i in xrange(len(tagged) - 3))
```

Here's a driver for the program:

```
s1 = [('This', 'DT'), ('feature', 'NN'), ('would', 'MD'), ('be', 'VB'), ('nice', 'JJ'), ('to', 'TO'), ('have', 'VB')]
s2 = [('I', 'PRP'), ('am', 'VBP'), ('able', 'JJ'), ('to', 'TO'), ('delete', 'VB'), ('the', 'DT'), ('group', 'NN'), ('functionality', 'NN')]

def would_be(tagged):
   return any(['would', 'be', 'JJ'] == [tagged[i][0], tagged[i+1][0], tagged[i+2][1]] for i in xrange(len(tagged) - 2))

def am_able_to(tagged):
    return any(['am', 'able', 'to', 'VB'] == [tagged[i][0], tagged[i+1][0], tagged[i+2][0], tagged[i+3][1]] for i in xrange(len(tagged) - 3))

sent1 = ' '.join(s[0] for s in s1)
sent2 = ' '.join(s[0] for s in s2)

print("Is '{1}' of type 'would be' + adj? {0}".format(would_be(s1), sent1))
print("Is '{1}' of type 'am able to' + verb? {0}".format(am_able_to(s1), sent1))

print("Is '{1}' of type 'would be' + adj? {0}".format(would_be(s2), sent2))
print("Is '{1}' of type 'am able to' + verb? {0}".format(am_able_to(s2), sent2))
```

This correctly outputs:

```
Is 'This feature would be nice to have' of type 'would be' + adj? True
Is 'This feature would be nice to have' of type 'am able to' + verb? False
Is 'I am able to delete the group functionality' of type 'would be' + adj? False
Is 'I am able to delete the group functionality' of type 'am able to' + verb? True
```

If you'd like to generalize this, you can change whether you're checking the literal words or their POS tag.

Comment: I were to do something generic like am_able_to(s1), I get a list index out of range error. Other than that, it works. Thanks!

Comment: Corrected the functions.

Comment: thanks Erip. I tested would_be on another sentence  "I am able to delete the group functionality" and I still get a list index out of range error.

Comment: @newdev14 What's the POS tag list for that sentence? I don't have nltk on this machine.

Comment: [('I', 'PRP'), ('am', 'VBP'), ('able', 'JJ'), ('to', 'TO'), ('delete', 'VB'), ('the', 'DT'), ('group', 'NN'), ('functionality', 'NN')]

Comment: @newdev14 It worked on my machine. Are you sure you copied the new functions?

Comment: Strange, yes I did copy those over. Did you try this new sentence with the  would_be function? That's where I get the error...