# How to find word combinations using POS tags using NLTK 3 in Python 3.5

Tags: python, nltk

I am writing a program that will:

1. open a .txt or .xml file and tag its contents using TreeTagger (a syntactic tagger)
2. identify all instances of determiners (DT) followed by common nouns (NN)

The program is not generating any errors. However, it doesn't return anything. If you see what I'm doing wrong, please do tell me.

This is the relevant part of my program:

```
tagger = treetaggerwrapper.TreeTagger(TAGLANG = 'en')
tagged_text = tagger.tag_text(text)
#tags the text

nltk_text = nltk.Text(tagged_text)
bigram_list = list(bigrams(nltk_text))

for (w1, t1), (w2, t2) in nltk.bigrams(bigram_list):
   if t1.startswith('DT') and t2.startswith('NN') :
        p.pprint(w1, w2)
#identifies instances of 'DT' followed by 'NN'
else:
    print('No matches found')`
```

Comment: Shameless plug: try this secret function in `nltk_cli`. http://stackoverflow.com/a/34742540/610569

Comment: Thanks, but I really need to use POS tags.

Comment: But do note that noun phrase patterns might be sub-optimal If you have "the train driver", "DT NN" -> would have never gotten the "driver".