# find job role from text data

Tags: python, regex, nlp, nltk

I have a text file from which i have to extract on what role the people are working. "Mechanical engineer","software developer" etc.
I have used NLTK to extract this using grammer like,

```
grammer= r"""
          NP: {<NN.*|JJ>*<NN.*>}  """
```

the result i am getting is good, but still for few documnets junk is coming. for those lines i want to apply Regular expressions.

my sample texts are like this.

- "I am software developement engineer in microsoft"
- "I am mechanical engineer with 10 years experience"

what i want is, I will extract two or three words before "Engineer".
I m using regular expression like,

```
regex=re.compile('|'.join([r'(?:\S+\s)?\S*[eE]ngineer']))
```

but, it extracts only one word before the specific word. How to make it to extract two or more words.?

i tried putting {2-3} in place of "?" in expression. but i am not getting desired result.

Is my approach correct ?
or any other approach to extract this specific phrase in better way ?

Comment: if you will extract two words in second example you will get `am mechanical engineer`..is that ok?

Comment: check **[this](https://regex101.com/r/xR6eU5/1#pcre)**

Comment: thats what my problem is. i don want to extract junk words. Its where i am stuck., but anyhow i can exclude words like 'am' before applying regEX.

Comment: that will be impossible..you require machine learning(or dictionary of junk works) for that..

Comment: `am` is not a "junk" word, it is either a notional, or an auxiliary, or a link verb (in grammar). Thus, you may precise what parts of speech/word forms you do not want to "extract" and use NLTK to annotate the input and remove the tokens based on the annotations. Then, you can apply regex to get the 1-2 words before/after the keywords. Like [`((?:\S+\s+){0,3})engineer\s*((?:\S+\s+){0,3})`](https://regex101.com/r/lK2qY4/1) or something like that.

Comment: Use a chunker instead of regex. E.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34738782/match-pos-tag-and-sequence-of-words

Answer (score 1):

The regex

```
 (\w+\s){2,3}dog
```

Will match

```
over the lazy dog
the lazy dog
```

In

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog the lazy dog
```

This should get you started I think