# Dependency parsing of noun chunks in spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy

There's a [couple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39241709/how-to-generate-bi-tri-grams-using-spacy-nltk?rq=1) [of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53598243/is-there-a-bi-gram-or-tri-gram-feature-in-spacy/53612262#53612262) existing questions about getting noun chunks in spacy, which is [relatively straightforward](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#noun-chunks).

What I'm interested in is replicating the dependency parsing on top of pre-specified ngrams inside a sentence. Like in the example below, from [this](https://youtu.be/jpWqz85F_4Y?t=991) spacy talk, where `Alex Smith` and `East London` are treated as a single token in the dependency parse.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was probably done via `options` parameters where you specify
`"collapse_phrases" : True`

Details at https://spacy.io/api/top-level#options-dep

Example which creates a svg file which you can open in your browser

```
import spacy
from spacy import displacy
from pathlib import Path

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', parse=True, tag=True, entity=True)

doc = nlp("Alex Smith was fatally stabbed in East London")
print(doc.ents)
options = {"color": "white", "collapse_phrases" : True, "bg": "#000000"}
svg = displacy.render(doc, style="dep", options=options)

output_path = Path("dependency_plot.svg")
output_path.open("w", encoding="utf-8").write(svg)
```